# MySQL select parent followed by its children and ordered by

Tags: mysql, sql, hierarchy

I have one level hierarchy table structure using Adjacency List Model. It could be summarized as follows:

```
id    parent_id      title          created_at

1     null           name1          2017-05-30 08:05:00
2     null           name2          2017-05-30 08:15:00
3     1              another name   2017-05-30 09:00:00
4     1              new name       2017-05-30 08:06:00
5     2              new title      2017-05-30 08:18:04
6     null           lorem          2017-05-30 08:04:00
```

What I need to get is an sql query that returns every row of null `parent_id` i.e the parent followed by its children ordered by `created_at` Something like the following:

```
id    parent_id      title          created_at

6     null           lorem          2017-05-30 08:04:00 
1     null           name1          2017-05-30 08:05:00
4     1              new name       2017-05-30 08:06:00
3     1              another name   2017-05-30 09:00:00
2     null           name2          2017-05-30 08:15:00
5     2              new title      2017-05-30 08:18:04
```

I have tried

```
SELECT COALESCE(`parent_id`, `id`) as pid, title, created_at 
FROM `items` 
ORDER BY created_at
```

But it does not succeeded the `another name` record came separately at the end of the result set.

This is [sql fiddle for the case](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3dd87/3/0)

**Notice** In the real case the id is an UUID string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this small variation on your work:

```
SELECT id, parent_id, title, created_at 
FROM `items` 
ORDER BY COALESCE(`parent_id`, `id`), created_at
```

In this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3dd87/10

**Revised** to order parents by timestamp and children within parents by timestamp:

```
SELECT id
     , parent_id
     , title
     , created_at 
     , COALESCE((SELECT created_at FROM items as parent WHERE parent.id = items.parent_id),created_at) parent_created_at
  FROM items 
 ORDER 
    BY parent_created_at
     , created_at
```

New fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3dd87/18

Comment: It work as nearest as I need, but It does not return the row of `id` = `6` first in spite of its datetime is the first one.

Comment: So, to clarify your question, you want the result ordered by `created_at` for the parents, but the children to come after their parent in `created_at` order?

Comment: Yes it is as you regarded i.e parents ordered by created_at and each parent is followed by its children also ordered by created_at

Comment: **The revised solution** is more strong one, it allows more abilities to ORDER specially with LEFT joins. Indeed it is a **great** solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want:

```
SELECT COALESCE(`parent_id`, `id`) as pid, title, created_at 
FROM `items` 
ORDER BY COALESCE(`parent_id`, `id`), created_at
```